# returning more than one variable in render of django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I define `home` request in `views.py`,

```
db=client.inventory_data
def home(request):
    collection_data_1 = db['orders']
    mydata = list(collection_data.find())
    return render(request,'home.html',{'mydata': mydata})
```

The above function works fine but when I try to return one more list, it **does not** work.

```
def home(request):
    collection_data_1 = db['orders']
    collection_data_2 = db['product']
    mydata = list(collection_data_1.find())
    product_data = list(collection_data_2.find())
    return render(request,'home.html',{'mydata': mydata},{'product_data':product_data})
```

**I want to return both the list, how can we achieve this? looking for kind help.**

Comment: Why not combine the dictionaries? `render(request, 'home.html', {'mydata': mydata, 'product_data': product_data})`

Comment: No problem!  I've posted a more in-depth response as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply combine the two dictionaries into one: `{'mydata': mydata, 'product_data': product_data}`

```py
def home(request):
    collection_data_1 = db['orders']
    collection_data_2 = db['product']
    mydata = list(collection_data_1.find())
    product_data = list(collection_data_2.find())

    return render(request,'home.html',{'mydata': mydata, 'product_data': product_data})
```

The reason that it didn't work when you passed in the two dictionaries separately is because `render` accepts `context` (a dictionary) as the third argument and `content_type` (a string) as the fourth argument, so when you passed in two dictionaries, you were passing in a dictionary as the `content_type`.

If it helps, here's what you originally had with the variable names annotated:

```py
render(
   request=request,
   template_name='home.html',
   context={'mydata':mydata},
   content_type={'product_data':product_data},
)
```

And here's what you have now:

```py
render(
   request=request,
   template_name='home.html',
   context={'mydata': mydata, 'product_data': product_data}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def home(request):
    # ...
    return render(request,'home.html',{'mydata': mydata, 'product_data':product_data})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def home(request):
    collection_data_1 = db['orders']
    collection_data_2 = db['product']
    mydata = list(collection_data_1.find())
    product_data = list(collection_data_2.find())
    context = {
     'mydata': mydata,
     'product_data': product_data
    }
    return render(request,'home.html', context=context)
```